# php: stream image from disk to buffer without reading it completely in memory

Tags: php

I have a file that reads a file from disk (from a directory not accessible to the webserver) and just serves it.

Is there a way to stream it to the browser without loading it fully into memory?

I suppose that this

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo file_get_contents($pic);
```

reads the whole thing in memory.

Comment: FYI, most file functions work the way you want. `file_get_contents()` and `file()` are maybe the only exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `readfile()` function, it reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php